# Why is し added at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

A person says these phrases:

> 嫌ではないです(it's not disgusting)
>
> というか... (I mean...)
>
> どっちかっていうと (If I had to choose) - /I'm not sure about this translation I made here/
>
> ...気持ちいいし (and it feels good?)

I know し means "and", "in addition", "what's more", etc but I don't know why is at the end of this sentence since there's no enumeration or additional comment. Perhaps I misunderstood something in my translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

し at the end of a sentence can be used to state a reason as l'électeur suggested. It's especially for negative reasons.

e.g.) このアパートは借りたくないですね。古いですし、汚いですし、家賃も高いですし。

But し is **also a slangy suffix used by young people.**

> 十代から二十代前半の女子が最近当たり前のように 会話や文章の語尾に「し」を付けているのが気になる。
>   頻繁に聞く例としては『っていうか、誰だし』の「誰だ」の後に着く「し」

[【若者言葉　語尾に付ける～「し」】 - amurohair](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/amurohair01/20100917/1284740431)

> 最近、知人やネットで、語尾に不自然に「し」をつける場面を多数見かけます。
>   例え ば、 「せっかく来たんだからゆっくりしてけし。」とか、 「今の話もう少し笑えし。」とか、 「そんなこと言うなし。」とか。

[「～し。」というのは流行りの若者言葉なんですかし。最近、知人やネット... - Yahoo!知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1147677316)

> 最近｢○○すんなし！｣みたいな、語尾が｢なし｣の否定的な話し方というか、ネットとかでもみかける言葉なんですが、あれってなんなんですか？

[最近の流行り言葉？最近｢○○すんなし！｣みたいな、語尾が｢なし｣の否定... - Yahoo!知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14142073534)

This seems to be derived from the Koshu dialect. The original sense looks like a strong order or request.

> これは、朝のテレビ小説「花子とアン」で一躍？有名になった甲州弁です。
>   「～し」で「～しなさい」という、強い依頼・命令を表します。「馬鹿にすんなし」、「ふざけんなし」、「頑張れし」、「仲良くしろし」など、通常の命令形の後ろに「し」を付けてその意味を強調するのが基本的な使い方です。

[「馬鹿にすんなし」、「ふざけんなし」などたまに「～し」を語尾につけること... - Yahoo!知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13154523688)

It seems to me し in the sentence you've shown is a slang. It still makes sense without し.

Answer (score 8):

> I know し means "and", "in addition", "what's more", etc.

But that is not what the 「し」 means in this context.  In his context, 「し」 means the same thing as 「から」 or 「ので」.  In other words, it is used to ***state a reason*** for something.

> 「嫌{いや}ではないです　というか... どっちかっていうと ...気持{きも}ちいい**し**」

＝

> 「というか... どっちかっていうと ...気持ちいい**し**　嫌ではないです」

「気持ちいい」 ("it feels good") is the reason for 「嫌ではない」 ("I don't dislike it").

It is an everyday occurence for Japanese speakers to locate a conjunctive at the end of a sentence.  I would be surprised if you have not encountered sentences ending with 「が」、「から」、「ので」, etc.  This time, the conjunctive was a  「し」.

Comment: Thanks. I had read about that meaning of し but I had forgotten it. One last thing, if it doesn't bother you, could you tell me if my translation of どっちかっていうと is correct?

Comment: That would actually depend on the context, but the expression is often used to mean "rather A than B", "on the A side", etc.  So, if you meant to say "to choose the right word", then that would be good.