# What does the word 「しのう」 mean in this sentence?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga, role-language

It is said by an old man who looks like wanting to teach boxing to a young man.

> 青山くんよ　ふたりきりの人目につかんところにいこう　折り入ってひみつに伝授したいこともある**しのう**

I'm not sure if it is related to the word 死ぬ in volitional form because it unlikely fits into the context.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57712/why-is-%e3%81%97-added-at-the-end-of-this-sentence, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58439/%e3%81%97-at-the-end-of-the-sentence

Comment: 「しのう」here has nothing to do with 「死ぬ」.