# もしたし -- Grammar point or vocabulary?

Tags: grammar, particle-し

I'm having some trouble understanding this sentence:

> バスケやってたよ。ちょっと熱血【ねっけつ】してた、遅く【おそく】まで残ってシュート練習もしたし

Specifically stuck on the trailing "もしたし", I can't find anything suitable on Google that describes it as a grammar point/conjugation, but my dictionary isn't returning any words. Is this "練習　も　したし"?  What is the meaning here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 練習　も　した＋し: "also practiced" + the explanatory clause ending conjunctive
particle し. For し's usage see these answers:

[Usage of ”し” particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59151/30454)

[し at the end of the sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58445/30454)

[Why is し added at the end of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57714/30454)